ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'N/'
I am working on a Machine Learning project that predicts the price electric cars on Jupyter Notebook.
I run this cell on Jupyter Notebook:
p = regressor.predict(df2)

I get this error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16424\818753220.py in <module>
----> 1 p = regressor.predict(df2)

~\.conda\envs\electricvehiclepriceprediction\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in predict(self, X, check_input)
    465         """
    466         check_is_fitted(self)
--> 467         X = self._validate_X_predict(X, check_input)
    468         proba = self.tree_.predict(X)
    469         n_samples = X.shape[0]

~\.conda\envs\electricvehiclepriceprediction\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)
    431         """Validate the training data on predict (probabilities)."""
    432         if check_input:
--> 433             X = self._validate_data(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr", reset=False)
    434             if issparse(X) and (
    435                 X.indices.dtype != np.intc or X.indptr.dtype != np.intc

~\.conda\envs\electricvehiclepriceprediction\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    564             raise ValueError("Validation should be done on X, y or both.")
    565         elif not no_val_X and no_val_y:
--> 566             X = check_array(X, **check_params)
    567             out = X
    568         elif no_val_X and not no_val_y:

~\.conda\envs\electricvehiclepriceprediction\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    744                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    745                 else:
--> 746                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    747             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    748                 raise ValueError(

~\.conda\envs\electricvehiclepriceprediction\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __array__(self, dtype)
   1991 
   1992     def __array__(self, dtype: NpDtype | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
-> 1993         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
   1994 
   1995     def __array_wrap__(

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'N/'

What did I try?
I tried using the following code:
uv = np.nanpercentile(df2['Base MSRP'], [99])[0]*2
df2['Base MSRP'][(df2['Base MSRP']>uv)] = uv
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
cols = ['County', 'City', 'State', 'ZIP Code', 'Model Year', 'Make', 'Model', 'Electric Vehicle Type', 'Clean Alternative Fuel Vehicle (CAFV) Eligibility']
for col in cols:
    le.fit(t[col])
    df2[col] = le.transform(df2[col]) 
    print(le.classes_)
regressor.fit(x, y)
p = regressor.predict(df2)

Here is the link to my notebook: https://github.com/SteveAustin583/electric-vehicle-price-prediction-revengers/blob/main/revengers.ipynb
How to fix this issue?

Your object df2 contains a string which doesn't look like a float. It contains the string 'N/' somewhere. Remove the string and you won't get the error

@smac89 Are you referring to this line? l=df[(df['Expected Price ($1k)']=='N/')].index

How could they refer to that line, when this line is nowhere to be found in your post (external links doesn't count, btw, in case it is there :D. You can provide links, but post should be readable without them)? They are referring to error message: could not convert string to float: 'N/'. You have a string in your data. We don't have your data, so can't tell you where. But that is the error. You can't do regression from non numerical data (well, I guess. You didn't tell what regressor is neither. But most use numerical data, and this once seems to complain about non numerical data)

@chrslg I have already found the solution to my question. Please, scroll down to find it in the answer section. Nonetheless, thanks for reaching out.

I did saw the auto-answer. And did it before I commented. But, well, that question was submitted for reopen. And even tho you anto-answer, it is sill no eligible for reopen, I was asked to vote, and when I vote against reopening, I find more correct to let a comment saying what could be improved in the question. What could be improved in your question is to include what needed to see the bug. No doubt you had what is needed on your computer, and that is why you solved the problem. But we haven't.

Understand that [so] is not a free debuging service. You can't just say "since my problem is solved, it doesn't matter anymore". It is a wiki-like built Q&A database. And as is, I am sure your personnal problem is solved, but your question and its own-answer can't help any future reader. Now, you may don't care anymore. And that's fine. Your aren't forced to want to take time to improve the question and help future users. But if you don't care, I guess you don't care neither that the question remain closed. And that comment is more for those who submitted the question for reopening.

@chrslg What's the point of adding super long irrelevant comment here on a question which I have already solved with the help of a suggestion from a previous commenter? You might not have the capacity to give me suggestion to fix the problem or have the time to look into my code on Github repo. But there was a previous commenter who did take time to look into the code on my GitHub repository and provide useful suggestion. If you can't do that, please don't bother texting me. But if you want to get involved in a meaningful discussion, like improving my solution, you are welcome to do that.

@chrslg And I know Stackoverflow is not a free debugging service. You don't have to teach me about that. But I think you should teach yourself about how to talk nicely and professionally. Those are the traits you clearly lack. And my question is actually going to help future readers of this platform. Because this question is about a Kaggle dataset on electric vehicle prices. Even my question is also related to code of a solution of Kaggle regarding the dataset. So, anyone who is interested in the electric vehicle dataset will find my question and answer very useful.

I have found a solution. I have replaced "N" with "-1" by using this code:
df2 = df2[df2['Model Year'] != 'N/']  # Filter out rows where 'Model Year' is 'N/'

for col in cols:
    df2[col] = df2[col].replace('N/', -1)
    le.fit(df2[col])
    df2[col] = le.transform(df2[col]) 
    print(le.classes_)

